# Report shows date instead of datetime on Webi export?

Tags: mysql, oracle, datetime-format, webi

I am using Web Intelligence for reporting however, the SQL script i use runs fine within Oracle where it displays the date and time of a column.

But when i run this report through web intelligence and then export, it only displays the date.

I am probably missing something incredibly easy but I cant see it.

Comment: Just to add to this, when the Excel file is exported, it looks like the time format is there but the cell format is incorrect. Is there another way to amend the cell format before its sent?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

All you should have to do is explicitly set a format rather than leaving it as the default format.

[image]

And I get this...

[image]

Comment: Thanks Isaac. Really appreciated.

that worked great! Is there any way to remove the AM / PM format and just have 24 HOUR time?

Comment: Sure. You just need to create a Custom Format. All the options can be found [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/819e1e8fbbdf48a9a6129b44216e15ab/4.2/en-US/4721c57e6e041014910aba7db0e91070.html).

Comment: If this answer is correct, kindly mark it as so. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Isaac. It does, thank you! Apologies for the late delay in responding. Not sure how to mark it as answered though, sorry.

Comment: I guess the correct terminology is "Accepted".  https://stackoverflow.com/tour